# Why a tensorflow model with Spatial Pyramid Pooling layers is slower than a sequential, vanilla model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a U-net type model with a minor variation in the architecture which is the Atrous Spatial Pyramid pooling (ASPP) layer at the bottleneck after the encoder. I profiled the model during one forward pass and used tensorboard to check the tracer_view to see which part of the model has the highest latency.
[Profiler Tracer View with ASPP layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdvmv.png)
This revealed that there's a lot of idle GPU time at ASPP computation. I double checked it by removing the ASPP layer and the just connected the encoder to the decoder. In this experiment, the idle time that was previously there disappeared.
[Profiler Tracer View without ASPP layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG6uV.png)
I understand that the second model example would be a bit smaller than the former.

This is how my model looks like with ASPP layer. And to I just commented those ASPP layers out to profile the model without ASPP layers.

**With ASPP**

```
def get_custom_deeplab(image_size: tuple, num_classes: int):
    """
    This model uses a vanilla CNN backbone. This model also uses upsampling2d in place of conv2d transpose
    """
    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(image_size[0], image_size[1], 3))
    conv1 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(input_layer)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv4)
#######ASPP layers
    out_1 = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), dilation_rate=1, padding='same')(pool4)
    out_6 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), dilation_rate=6, padding='same')(pool4)
    out_12 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), dilation_rate=10, padding='same')(pool4)
    out_14 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), dilation_rate=14, padding='same')(pool4)
    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([out_1, out_6, out_12, out_14])
########ASPP's output
    x = Conv2D(256, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), dilation_rate=1, padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        (2,2),interpolation="bilinear",
        )(x)
        
    skip_connection_1 = pool3
    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x,skip_connection_1])
    x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        (2,2),interpolation="bilinear",
        )(x)
    skip_connection_2 = pool2
    x = layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([x,skip_connection_2])
    x = Conv2D(128, (1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        (2,2),interpolation="bilinear",
        )(x)
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform', kernel_constraint=max_norm(3), padding='same')(x)
    x = layers.UpSampling2D(
        (2,2),interpolation="bilinear",
        )(x)
    x = Conv2D(
        num_classes,
        kernel_size=1,
        padding="same",
        use_bias=True,
        kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.HeNormal(),
        )(x)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer,outputs=x)
```

But, I would like to know if there's any workaround to mitigate the problem of GPU idle time when the model has layers like ASPP?

Comment: You might want to post this to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/. It's a portal dedicated to machine learning and deep learning related queries.

Comment: @AzharKhan But I want to specifically find out why this is happening in Tensorflow and how to mitigate this.